# How to find the exact solution in one dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations, variational-analysis

Let $\Omega = (-1,1)$ be partitioned into two subdomains $\Omega_1 = (-1,0)$ and $\Omega_2 = (0,1)$.

I'd like to find the exact solution in one dimension:
Find $u\in H_0^1(\Omega),\ $ such that :$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} \kappa\nabla u\cdot \nabla v = \int_\Omega v$, $\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, where $\kappa|_{\Omega_1} = \alpha$ and $\kappa|_{\Omega_2} = 1$ .

Actually I know this equation exists a unique solution... but I don't know how to solve it , because I don't know how to describe the shape of $H_0^1(\Omega)$, and I just know its dense subset is $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: The strong form is $(\nabla^2)(u(x))=-\frac{1}{\kappa}$, which you can use on each subinterval.

Comment: I'v tried this. Solving the ode on each subinterval will get four unknowns but there are only one boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strong form is $-\kappa \Delta u(x) =1$. Then the solution is quadratic on each subinterval. To determine the four integration constants you take the boundary condition $u(\pm 1)=0$ and the continuity condition $u(0^+) = u(0^-)$. Then one condition is missing, which can be obtained as follows:
$$
\int_\Omega v = \int \kappa u'v'= \int_{-1}^0 \alpha u'v' + \int_0^1 u'v'
= -\int_{-1}^0  \alpha u'' v  - \int_0^1 u''v + (\alpha u'(0^-) - u'(0^+))v(0).
$$
In order that this expression is zero for all $v$, the condition $\alpha u'(0^-) - u'(0^+)= 0$ is required, which fixes the last integration constant.

Comment: I am a little confused about the continuity. Why it has to be continuous at zero.

Comment: And why don't let the derivative be continuous?

Comment: $H^1$ functions are continuous (on 1d domains)

Comment: Partial integration of the weak formulation on each subdomain separately gives you the condition on the derivative. If $\alpha\ne1$ it will not be continuous at zero.

Comment: So we use the strong form and the weak form together... So now i don't know why  we can use the strong form......

Comment: I know it . Thank a lot again!